# excel-Return true if range is ordered. Return false if first cell in range is blank or there is a blank cell in the middle of the range

Tags: arrays, excel, algorithm

Have been trying to solve this without just creating an IF for every condition. I want to create a formula that returns true if a range is in order but returns false in the following conditions
The first cell in the range is blank
There exist a blank cell in the middle of the range
The range is out of order
(Blank cells at the END of the range are okay)
I cannot seem to create a formula capable of this. I've attached an image for clarification. Thanks for any help!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use offset ranges to compare adjacent cells. The conditions are

(1) No instances of the number in a cell being greater than the number in the following cell, unless the following cell is blank

(2) No instances of a cell being blank, where the following cell is not blank.

```
=IF(COUNT(A2:F2)=0,"",SUM((A2:E2>B2:F2)*(B2:F2<>""))+SUM((A2:E2="")*(B2:F2<>""))=0)
```

[image]